# Error on Command Prompt while pip install -e. (OpenAI Universe)

Tags: python, linux, windows, artificial-intelligence

According to OpenAI official website, OpenAI Universe can be installed by:

```
git clone https://github.com/openai/universe.git
cd universe
pip install -e .
```

I manage to do the first 2 but the third line didn't work. I get an error which I couldn't troubleshoot after surfing the net for quite a while.

[image: Image of Error on Command Prompt]

I am running windows. Could it be the reason why it isn't able to install? Sorry if this is a dumb question, I've barely started python.

Comment: Please don't post error messages or code as images. I can't read the image even now that it's inline because the colors are wonky. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: The [instructions](https://github.com/openai/universe) say it's supported on Linux and OSX so it's quite likely that you can't get it to work on Windows. Installing a virtualized Linux (or heaving Windows overboard entirely; you can thank me later) might be the easiest way forward.